# Inserting value with # as a parameter in table with dql using $_GET

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

- i want to insert string with a '#' like this #abcd

*i have written insert code in doctrine like this

```
         $social = new Entities\SocialKeyword;
         $social->setEventId($_GET["eventId"]);
         $social->setHashtag($_GET["hashtag"]);

        $this->em->persist($social);
        $this->em->flush();
```

*but when i am providing parameter in url like this

serve.biz/index.php/socialkey/abc?eventId=6666&hashtag=#jhfskfgvgusdisdfds

in this condition no value or string is added to colum 'hashtag' and its empty

but when i try this
serve.biz/index.php/socialkey/abc?eventId=6666&hashtag=jhfskfgvgusdisdfds (mean without '#')

its working fine.

so how can i insert it with #.

need help.

Answer (score 0):

a hashtag has a meaning in a URL and is not part of the query string, if you want to pass it as a get parameter, you have to escape it.

have a look at [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php); the urlencoded string for a hastag is `%23`, so you should try this:

```
serve.biz/index.php/socialkey/abc?eventId=6666&hashtag=%23jhfskfgvgusdisdfds
```

Having said that, it's useless to also pass the hashtag, because that's more part of how you want to visually represent a tag, and it doesn't even need to be in de DB. It would be better to add this while rendering a tag in the view...

Comment: what i am doing creating a API which will take data from tweeter. so there will be data with hashtag('#'), and i have to store them into my database. So its compulsary for me include the hashtag.

Comment: well, then you have to escape it correctly, as I mentioned.

Comment: its working fine but what, when a user enter a hashtag as like this- #abcdefgh but not like %23abcdefgh

Comment: the user should use #, you should parse this and escape the input before using it... rule #1 in software: filter input, escape output!